# Correspondence between PCA principal components and the original variables

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I'm want to apply PCA to the kaggle's Titanic [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic)

For now I'm just taking the columns that have numeric values and dropping the NaN  values, So I have five variables, actually four if we ignore the depending variable ('Survived').

[image]

I have this loaded into a DataFrame df, if I took five components using PCA:

```
pca_model = PCA(n_components=5)
pca_model.fit(df)
pca_model.explained_variance_ratio_

[  9.30197643e-01   6.93699966e-02   2.24377672e-04   1.49076254e-04
   5.89069784e-05]
```

I got that 93 percent of the variance comes from the first component. 
Is it possible how can I get this same values from the original variables? E.G. Age -> 0.3 of the variance 
     Fare -> 0.6

Can I now which percentage of the principal component is given by each of the original variables?

Answer (score 1):

Each component of the PCA is a linear combination of all of the original variables. You can observe the role of each original variable in different PCA components using `pca_model.components_`.